# Usage of execPopulate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got stuck with using execPopulate. I've read the documentation, but I don't still get it.

When should I use execPopulate() after populate() and when not?

Here I can't and don't have to use it:

```
  const courses = await Course.find().populate("userId")
```

But here I must:

```
const user = await User.findById("323223ad");
const user = await user
.populate('cart.items.courseId')
.execPopulate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one:

```
const courses = await Course.find().populate("userId")
```

operates over the model class... it finds and populate those fields. No execPopulateNeeded.

The second one:

```
const user = await User.findById("323223ad");
const user = await user
.populate('cart.items.courseId')
.execPopulate()
```

Operates over an instance of a class (over a MongoDB record instance).

You need to specify when to execute the `populate()`... you can chain many `populate()`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain, if I use just:

const user = await User.findById("323223ad").populate('cart.items.courseId')

I shouldn't use execPopulate()?

Comment: Yup, you don't need to use `execPopulate()` in this case.