# Populate and exepopulate didn’t work in mongoose.js and Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this route, but it didn't give a result which I had expected. It gave the 200 code as a response.

And a console.log statement before populate is working, but after it is not. What did I miss to do or how should I be working with populate?

For more info :

In user model

```
userSchema.virtual('wishes',{
    ref:'Wishes',
    localField:"_id",
    foreignField:"owner"

})
```

In wishes model :

```
 owner:{
        type:monoogse.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true,
        ref:'users'
    }
```

The route :-

```
router.get("/wishlist", auth, async(req, res) => {

    const sort = {}, match = {};

    if(req.query.sortBy)
    {
        const parts = req.query.sortBy.split(':');
        sort[parts[0]] = parts[1] === 'dec' ? -1 : 1;
    }

    try
    {
        console.log("likes")
        // const tasks = await Task.find({owner: req.user._id});
        await req.user.populate(
        {
            path: 'wishes',
            //     match,
            //     options:{
            //         limit: parseInt(req.query.limit),
            //         skip: parseInt(req.query.skip),
            //         sort
            //  }

        }).execPopulate();

        console.log(req.user.likes, "likes")
        console.log("likes2")
        res.send(req.user.likes)
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        res.send(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: `execPopulate` (body) or `exepopulate` (title)? Or `exePopulate` or `execpopulate`? Or something else? What is the link to documentation for it?

Comment: It may be [execPopulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67063573/usage-of-execpopulate).

Comment: it's  execpopulate

Comment: but i still don't know why its not working or give me any error